# Custom search engine Button click

Tags: jquery, click

Im trying to call function on Custom Search Engine search button click.

Code at the moment i try is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".gsc-search-button input[type=button]").click(function()
{
  alert("1");
});
</script>
```

Doesnt work.

Site: http://akcijos.igloro.info/?q=Android

EDIT:

Found solution on post: [Bind click event to 'search' button in Google Custom Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560615/bind-click-event-to-search-button-in-google-custom-search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution of this on other stackoverflow post.

Reason:

> The search box is created with google js api after window.onload, therefore the .bind() fails. Solved the problem with jquery.live().

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input.gsc-search-button[type=submit]").live('click', function()
{
  console.log("clicked");
  alert("1");
});
</script>
```

Other post url: [Bind click event to 'search' button in Google Custom Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560615/bind-click-event-to-search-button-in-google-custom-search)

Comment: Right you are! didnt think about that ;) - thanks for directing me to the right spot.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to override the default action of pressing the button? You could try doing this:

```
$(".gsc-search-button input[type=button]").click(
    function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("1");
    }
);
```

Comment: No. Not to override. Just to call other function which should write query value to database.