# Google Custom Search Engine - control results on click

Tags: javascript, html, web, onclick, google-custom-search

Im facing an issue with my project, I want to control the search results, which means when a user clicks on any result, there will be an action.

I am using "Google Custom Search Engine", to display search result.
This is the search box and result code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '000752459719902753414:o5xzy3na1va';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
    </script>
</head>
  <body>
    
    <div >
        <gcse:search></gcse:search>
    </div>
    
    </body>
  </html>
```

The results displays in this line `<gcse:search></gcse:search>`
I'm trying to figure out how can I control each result separately on click

thanks in advance..

Comment: By using google custom search engine you are linking direct to google's code (or your website's code once the the results are displayed). You will need to inspect to work out the names of the elements you wish to manipulate, then create a function to manipulate those elements (since you can't change google's code,  you can only create code which uses the same elements).  Normally you would attempt a task and post the code so far on SO. What you have asked is very broad.

Comment: yes that what i have tried, but unfortunately did not work.. this's the div tag name, google uses for the result: gsc-webResult gsc-result

Comment: this looks like a good solution by @Robin, it needs `jquery` library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560615/bind-click-event-to-search-button-in-google-custom-search
>The search box is created with google js api after window.onload, therefore the .bind() fails. Solved the problem with jquery.live().

`$("input.gsc-search-button[type=submit]").live('click',showResults);`  
`$(".gsc-clear-button").live('click', hideResults);`

Comment: Alternative solution by @Roman Lowsev http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673963/custom-search-engine-button-click